# Split a text by word from list of words and keep the word in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of addresses like:

```
addresses = [['123 Abc Ave Santa Monica, CA'], ['595 Apts 76 Box Rd Washington, DC'],['Avalon Apts 34 Plain St Dallas, TX']]
```

I am trying to split the addresses to get the street address, city, and state separately. Like so:

```
street_add = ['123 Abc Ave', '76 Box Rd', '34 Plain St']
city =  ['Santa Monica', 'Washington', 'Dallas']
state =  ['CA', 'DC', 'TX']
```

I have tried the solution from here to for using a list of words but I am unable to keep the string I'm splitting on: [Python. Split string using any word from a list of word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976827/python-split-string-using-any-word-from-a-list-of-word)

```
   #trails = ("(St)", "(Street)", "(Dr)", "(Drive)", "(Avenue)", "(Ave)", "(Court)", "(Road)")
    trails = ("St", "Street", "Dr", "Drive", "(Avenue)", "(Ave)", "(Court)", "(Road)")

    # \b means word boundaries.
    regex = r"\b(?:{}).*".format("|".join(trails))
    addresses = [re.split(regex, y) for x in addresses for y in x]
```

but this gives me:

```
[['123 Abc ', None, None, None, None, ''], ['76 Box', 'Road', None, None, None, ''], ['34 Plain', None, None, None, None, '']]
```

How can I get just the addresses, city, and state separately?

Comment: Don't use `split`, whose purpose is to give you the stuff *between* what gets matched.

Comment: Think carefully about what happens when you `format` the `trails` values into the regex, considering that some of them contain parentheses. What will those parentheses mean to the regex? Then, think about what you expect to be in each of the `.groups` of a match, according to the logic; and about how that corresponds to the result you want. Any remaining work is conceptually simpler than what you have already done, and there isn't a clear question about any of it here.